# How to place a UILabel on a UITabbar?

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I wish to place a UILabel on a UITabbar,how can I implement that ?

Comment: Just a guess, creating by code.

Comment: well , do you want that static or Dynamic ??

Comment: I wish to create one dynamically

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick, assuming you're using a `UINavigationController` with a toolbar:
(it has a flexible space on either side to center it.

```
CGRect myFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44);
UILabel *myLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:myFrame];
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:NULL];
UIBarButtonItem *labelItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:myLabel];
UIBarButtonItem *spaceItem2 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:NULL];
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spaceItem,labelItem,spaceItem2, nil] animated:YES];
```

Comment: The question was regarding a `UITabBar`, not a toolbar.